# GUI browser and editor for Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

Is there a GUI based editor for Neo4J? I know the default too for graph visualization in localhost:7474, but i am looking for a tool that allows GUI based editing as well.

Comment: I have found this tool which is quite easy to build your self - https://github.com/adadgio/neo4j-js-ng2 - Its not super pretty but it lets you manipulate the data in all kinds of ways as needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's the ancient webadmin still in Neo4j, go to "data browser" in  localhost:7474/webadmin

This one allows to do data modifications.

Comment: Sorry -1 as this is no longer true I'm afraid - That webadmin URL does not work for me (Ent 3.4.5)